# install application/x-executable files in Debian

Tags: debian, firefox

I've downloaded Mozilla Firefox for my Debian OS and it contains a **application/x-executable** file and i have no problem running it but i can't install it like a .deb file  .
how can i run it from the application menu or add it to favorites?

(Debian buster, Gnome 3.30.2, Firefox version 80.0.1 (64-bit))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a .desktop file for it. Create the file either in `~/.local/share/applications/` for your user only or `/usr/share/applications`, system-wide.

Sample `downloadedFirefox80.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox 80
Comment=manually downloaded Firefox
Exec=/{your-path}}/firefox %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=firefox
Categories=WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
StartupNotify=true
```

After .desktop file is created, the new application will be available on the application menu. Probably you won't even need to log out, in case you cannot locate it log out and log in and it'll be there.